# An curious exception: is the httpRequest Stream doesn't accept UTF8？

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying post some data via HttpWebRequest.

Here is the data:

```
        string data = string.Format("username={0}&password={1}", username, password);
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
```

There isn't any difference bewtwen UTF8 and ASCII in this case. The string is pure ASCII chars.

The code below  will throw an exception:

```
            using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
                string a = data.Substring(0, 1);
                string b = data.Replace(a, string.Empty);
                writer.Write(a);
                writer.Flush();
                writer.Write(b);
                writer.Flush();
            }//---->Last line with no code but right curly braces. Here's EXACTLY where the ex.StackTrace suggests.
```

This works perfectly:

```
            using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.ACSII); //---> from UTF8 to ACSII                   
                // ... the rest is same as before
            }
```

This also works perfectly:

```
            using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
               stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            }
```

The exception is this:

```
  The request was aborted: The request was canceled.
  StackTrace:
  at System.Net.ConnectStream.CloseInternal(Boolean internalCall, Boolean aborting)
  at System.Net.ConnectStream.System.Net.ICloseEx.CloseEx(CloseExState closeState)
  at System.Net.ConnectStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
  at System.IO.Stream.Close()
  at my function at the forementioned line.
```

The request:

```
            request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://-.-/takelogin.php");
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0";
            request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
            request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "zh-CN,zh;q=0.8,zh-TW;q=0.7,zh-HK;q=0.5,en-US;q=0.3,en;q=0.2");
            request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
            request.Referer = "https://-.-/login.php";
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.ContentLength = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(data);
            request.KeepAlive = true;
            request.Headers.Add("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
```

I want to know the internal reason in this situation...Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What content-type header are you sending, and does it include the optional charset attribute? e.g. `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded ; charset=UTF-8`?

Comment: Well, the error is an inability to dispose the stream because it was already aborted, so it makes sense it happens at the closing bracket of the `using` block... though I don't immediately see what would cause it to happen.

Comment: Are you setting the content length header accurately?

Comment: @JohnWu            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

Comment: @S.C. Yes it is set correctly besides my string is same in utf8 or ascii

Answer (score 2):

Encoding.UTF8 passes a “byte order mark” when used with StreamWriter, often called a BOM.

If you use new UTF8Encoding(false), that will not send the BOM, and things should work.

The Encoding.UTF8 is equivalent to new UTF8Encoding(true), where true is “write the BOM”.